# error TS2507: Type 'typeof Tapable' is not a constructor function type

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I created a private TypeScript library to use in few other projects I have. Its purpose is to hold shared TS models.

I'll simplify only the important parts of the library repo:

*index.ts:*

```
export interface IApp { ... }
```

*package.json:*

```
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "prepare": "npm run build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.7",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.6",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.2",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.0.3",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3"
  }
}
```

This is example `package.json` from another `server` nodeJs repo that depends on the lib:

*package.json:*

```
{
  "name": "my-server",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly ./src/index.ts",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "my-lib": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/me/my-lib.git",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.32",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^11.13.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.2"
  }
}
```

upon running `yarn install` inside the `server` nodeJs repo, I am getting this error:

```
$ yarn install
yarn install v1.15.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

$ npm run build

> my-lib@1.0.0 build C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v4\.tmp\1f8bdfc66f08780f32df98202058b430.f3e8cc10b42f696133e0e0e207296fcbbd45ba0e.prepare
> tsc

../../../../../../../node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:529:28 - error TS2507: Type 'typeof Tapable' is not a constructor function type.

529     class Compiler extends Tapable implements ICompiler {
                               ~~~~~~~

../../../../../../../node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:556:42 - error TS2507: Type 'typeof Tapable' is not a constructor function type.

556     abstract class MultiCompiler extends Tapable implements ICompiler {
                                             ~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! my-lib@1.0.0 build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-lib@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-10T16_00_57_077Z-debug.log
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

I have found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/webpack/tapable/issues/53), which suggest adding `@types/tapable@0.2.5`. I have tried adding it both to the library and the main repo but the issue still persist.

This happens both using `npm install` and `yarn install`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had this errno 2 issue and if similar, you may be having a lint issue analyzing the TypeScript code. Do a global search in your project, do you have the command `run lint` called anywhere prior to build/deploy?

Comment: thank you @mohsenmadi. I added and used now `tslint`, fixed all issues but the above issue still persist.

Comment: I believe you over simplified the provided information. First to clarify, what exact gives error, is it `npm install` or `npm run build`? I believe it's the build right? If so, you should also include your build config. Is it simply a `tsc` command?

Comment: @hackape thank you.
Running `yarn/npm install` inside the server project download the library and triggers `prepare` script which run `npm run build` -> `tsc`.
This for building the `/dist` dir to be available for using in the server.
The errors are coming from the `tsc` command.

Comment: This error is valid, tho its the tapable's fault. Now there's only two escapes. Either you add a custom `.d.ts` to fix that wrong types, or you figure out **why** tsc includes tapable as a source input, which seem strange unless your lib deps (NOT devDeps) on tapable in source code. If it's unnecessary, try exclude it from tsc source input.

Comment: You went the other way :-) My problem was running lint. Removing the `run lint` command is what did it for me.

Comment: Also, run your commands with `sudo`; lack of permission gives errors unrelated to permissions sometimes.

Comment: @hackape sounds right. any idea how to exclude it from tsc source input?

Comment: thank you both. I've found the solution. I had `~/node_modules` dir which somehow did all this mess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After successful `yarn install` at other dev computer, I assumed the problem is at my environment.

I have updated `Node.js`, `npm`, `yarn` to latest versions. removed all global packages. cleared `npm` & `yarn` cache. nothing worked.

Finally, I found I had `~/node_modules` dir with `tapable` inside it (along with few other packages). I removed that dir entirely and now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

TS `skipLibCheck` compiler option could help

Comment: not helping. :( even if it were, I prefer avoid skipping